# Import Maximo 7.5 tickets into Jira

Tags: jira, maximo

I'm looking for a programmatic way to export Maximo tickets and import them into Jira.  The reason is we currently have two ticketing systems and I'd like to give my internal customers access to a single Kanban board (Jira), to give visibility into what the team is working on and where they fit into the queue.  I've scoured the web and can't find an easy way to accomplish this.

Comment: You've looked at Maximo integration framework? You can export to xml, csv, or interface table. I don't know if it can be real time but you can definitely do in batches. I think there's a jira csv importer you can run from command line. That might allow you to automate ticket creation in jira. How you sync status changes though... That's a can of worms... :)

Comment: Can of worms is an understatement! :)  Thanks for the suggestions all.  Much appreciated.

Comment: @Sun is it possible to create communication between git and Maximo? For example if I commit a code to get evidention on Maximo that I've commited something?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro you should create a separate question. Not enough details your in comment to give a good answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use JIRA's import from CSV feature. You may need to modify the CSV in various ways to make it acceptable. If you have fewer than 100 tickets, retyping them is often faster